# Why are particular dll's deleted from Azure App Server site when deploying?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I have a .net app that I deploy to Azure. It is compiled to the directory c:\publish\bin under Release compile option, but for some reason it deletes one dll in particular , the System.Runtime.dll.
So before it starts to deploy it displays  this

```
Starting Web deployment task from source: 
manifest(C:\LocalWebProject\obj\Release\Package\My.SourceManifest.xml) to Destination: 
auto(). Deleting file (AzureAppService\bin\System.Runtime.dll).
Adding ACLs for path (MyWebProject)
```

Any ideas why this would happen ?

Answer (score 0):

> Particular dll's deleted from Azure App Server site when deploying:

*I've created a sample* `webapp` *using visual studio and was able to deploy it successfully to Azure.*

***Program.cs***:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

***appsettings.json:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

***Build on IIS Server:***

[image]

***Published to Azure:***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

***Need to check***:-

- Never put anything in `bin`. Bin is not a source folder for binaries rather, it is the destination location for binaries.

  [Dependency Tree](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Resolving-Binary-References-in-MSBuild.aspx)

  > .CsProj
  > |
  > classlibrary.dll
  > |
  > .binlibrary.dll
- It is preferable to think of the `bin` folder as it is created by a project as "output" directory; they should only contain files generated by the project `build`.
- Instead of using `build`, try `rebuild` which will perform cleanup and build the current project. Usually, the outputs from previous builds are kept with the `build` command. Therefore, it may result these kinds of dependency related actions like ***"deletion of specific dll files".*** `Rebuild` does remove them and build again.
- While cleaning up, it might remove the necessary dependencies also. It is possible to [restore deleting files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/restoring-accidentally-deleted-dll-files/9054031c-319a-4402-8176-890c612387b6).

**Note**:

1. I suggest, Use Visual studio while working with Web Apps to avoid these kinds of issues.
2. Check for `Visual Studio` version and update it to latest versions.

[image]

*Reference*: [dll files getting deleted](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94bd1c2c-3c92-4a29-b076-72f579a96790/dll-files-get-deleted-on-rebuild?forum=aspmvc)

Comment: I deploy using Devops , a  powershell script . something like the following:  # Init deployment procedure Run MSBuild to publish the project
    & "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" $SolutionPath `
    /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 `
    /p:DeployOnBuild=true `
    /p:PublishProfile=$DeploymentXmlFilePath `
    /p:Password=$password

Comment: the prooct is built in release mode to c:\publish\bin directory and there are 2 dlls i manually copy there before doing the deploy via the boave script. I would assume all dlls in that directory  are copied across to app service bin directory .

Comment: Make sure that there are no files present in bin folder except binaries. (dll's)